# What does "unique group table" mean in "Prove that there is a unique group table for $G$"?

Tags: group-theory, definition

I am currently trying to teach myself abstract algebra by working through Dummit and Foote's text, and one of the exercises asks us to prove that the group table for a specific group $G = \{1, a, b, c\}$ with all elements of order $\leq 3$ is unique. Does this simply mean that every entry of the group table has a unique value? This seems obvious for any group $G$, since for any $w,x,y,z\in G$, if $w \neq z$ but $xy = w$ and $xy = z$, then $y = x^{-1}w$ and $y = x^{-1}z$, which leads to the contradiction $w=z$ via the cancellation law.

I just wanted to make sure that I had the right definition in mind, since the other question on here about this exercise does not directly address this part of the exercise. They simply determine what the value of each product must be explicitly in the course of proving that the specific $G$ in the exercise is abelian.

Comment: They mean that there is precisely one group table which can be constructed using the given elements with the given constraint.

Comment: You don't know the specific group. All you have is information about it. Is the information sufficient to construct the multiplication table? That's the goal of the exercise.

Comment: Because $G$ has order $4$, by Lagrange all elements have order $2$, except for the identity element. So we  have $G=C_2\times C_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proving a group $G$ has a unique group table means that any table you create for the group can have its rows/columns rearranged to look like just one table.

I recommend writing out every table for groups of order $4$ first (you should get four different tables). At that point look carefully and you'll realize three of the tables are technically "the same" if you reorder the rows/columns (you'll learn later this means they're *isomorphic*). So then you'll have shown all groups with four elements only correspond to two different tables. What's left is to look at the order of the elements to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

No. It means that there is a unique way of defining a group structure in $\{1,a,b,c\}$ such that

- $1$ is the identity element;
- each element has order $\leqslant3.$